# J1 visa applying for Canadian student visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada, study, j1-visas

I am currently studying masters in the US and I hold a J1 visa.

I want to continue my PhD in a Canadian university can I apply for a Canadian student visa (assuming I have been accepted by Canadian University) or must I obtain the visa from my country of permanent residence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on [the official website of Citizenship and Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/apply-where.asp)

> You must select the visa office that serves your country of nationality or the country where you have been legally admitted for at least one year.

I would think that a J1 visa could be enough to satisfy this requirement but I am not sure.

Additionally, for temporary residence or study permits, you can apparently apply in any [Visa Application Centre](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/vac.asp) and your application will then be forwarded to the relevant visa office. If I understand this correctly (I never did it myself), you cannot choose which visa office will handle your application but you won't necessarily need to go to this office in person.